# count the number of connected induced subgraphs in a graph with bounded degree

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a graph where the maximum degree of a vertex is 4. I've been asked to find an efficient algorithm for counting how many connected induced subgraphs are in $G$.
What I have so far is a recursive algorithm but it runs in a complexity proportional to the number of subgraphs and that is just way to much (the algorithm actually finds the subgraphs instead of just counting how many are there). I would really appreciate any help on this.